# Windows 7 disappeared in list of Grub while loading

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2

Installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside the Windows 7 two weeks ago. Initially haven't any issues with that. day ago installed updates on Ubuntu and after restarting the system found the absence of Win7 in Grub list. Before the HDD has been partitioned on two volumes Disk C and Work Disk(don't remember the name). When doing the `fdisk -l`:

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa93031e0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   408833842   204415897+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       488386560   976773119   244193280    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       408834046   488386559    39776257    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       408834048   484421631    37793792   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       484423680   488386559     1981440   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3965 MB, 3965190144 bytes
49 heads, 48 sectors/track, 3292 cylinders, total 7744512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            8192     7744511     3868160    b  W95 FAT32
```

---

When `sudo mount /dev/sda ~/1 -o offset [488386560*512]`  - opens and mounts WORK disk.

Need help: how to See and mount disk C.
how to see and adjust the Grub to appear both systems in Grub menu when loading?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the there was a little error when rebuilding grub during the update process
Try to do a

```
sudo update-grub
```

and see if it generates it or not

Comment: Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done - this is what I've got